# Application window never appears (Gnome SSH Tunnel Manager)

Tags: unity, 12.10, xorg, window-manager, window

I'm having an issue with gSTM failing to generate a window, it opened once, prior to a reboot, and I had moved it to Workspace 3 (not sure if this is relevant)

I'm using Ubuntu 12.10 with a pretty much default Unity setup (minor, in-band modifications)

Now, following a reboot (no changes made) when gSTM is run, it will open the tunnels that I originally created, however it never displays a window.

Any ideas? Is there a way to debug the application to see if it even attempts to generate a window (capture xorg connection?)

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Go into your home directory and there is a folder called .gSTM. The files in there are the configurations of your tunnel servers.

For all servers change

```
<autostart>1</autostart>
```

to

```
<autostart>0</autostart>
```

then it works.

And don't tick autostart again ;)

Answer (score 2):

Go into your home directory and there is a folder called .gSTM rename it to something like .gSTM_OLD and load up the program then it should appear.

I think this is due to having the 'auto start' ticked.

Comment: This will lose all your current settings. Though.